# Must a reference to a pointer in c++ be casted before passing it to a method as an argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, argument-passing

I have a C++ code similar to following.

```
class TestA
{

};

class TestB
{
    bool CreateTestAObject( TestA *& arg );
};
```

Basically I have a class called `TestA`. And in another class called `TestB`, I have a method inside `TestB` called `CreateTestAObject( TestA *& arg )` that creates a new `TestA` object. The method must return a boolean indicating the success or the failure of the method. Therefore in order to return the newly created TestA object, I used the argument list with a reference to a pointer of type `TestA` class.

In main() function I did,

```
TestB objB;
TestA* ptrA = NULL;

objB.CreateTestAObject( ptrA  );
```

My problem is, when I compile this, I get the following error.

```
no matching function for call to TestB::CreateTestAObject(TestA *)
note: candidates are: bool TestB::CreateTestAObject(TestA *&)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the argument needed to be casted to `TestA*&`, and if so why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not direct answer to your question, but I would define this function as `TestA* CreateTestAObject()`, return NULL if failed. Simple is better.

Comment: I would've done that too. But the thing is, the API I'm writing, demands a method that returns a boolean, indicating the success or the failure. The only way to return the created object is through the argument list.

Comment: @Alex, I'd be against this option. Mixing the return value and error checking logic is a common place of errors. How likely are your callers to check that return value for NULL? Separating these two types of information is a good way to force callers to stop and think.

Comment: @kasper360, I think your code is OK. Did you try making `CreateTestAObject` `public` and see how it goes?

Comment: Your code looks good. Can you show more of the classes, and how you have implemented them?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code posted. Post the real code and the real error, must be something wrong when you transcribed your code to SO.

Comment: Your question lacks an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and you will get lots of wild guesses, bu no actual answers.